# What bmx logo is this please?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I was told it was an American rally but have been unable to find anything of that make. It was originally in chrome and has for some reason V brake lugs at the back.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The rear brakes are probably for U brakes, not V brakes, unless its relatively recent.

Comment: Thanks Criggie, I’ll swap the brakes for a U type and see how I get on. I assumed it was a V type as there were 3 holes on each side for where the springs are applied

Comment: A picture of the brake mounts would be more informative.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I’ll upload a new picture tomorrow

Comment: I added one of the full frame as it looks..

Comment: That rear dropout looks particularly distinctive.

Comment: Do you think it is a GT?

Comment: The v-brake mounts are for v-brakes!

Comment: Thanks JoeK, which makes me think it is a race BMX. I’ve never really been fond of V brakes on a BMX and always preferred U brakes

Comment: What does it say on the chainring?

Comment: Hey all! Super happy, I’ve finally found the make of the frame and can confirm it is a Raleigh Reaper. This particular one was made in ‘99. There is one on eBay with the original stickers and forks if you’d like to see.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/NOS-Raleigh-USA-Reaper-BMX-20-Frame-Fork/174456718527?hash=item289e6e44bf:g:qy8AAOSwRD5d~EEf

Comment: The frame you found on ebay is a great find and a perfect match. It is interesting that there is nothing in the BMX museum for a Raleigh Reaper https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/raleigh/ and there is nothing in bikepedia for Raleigh in 1999 showing a Reaper model. Makes me wonder where the stickers on the frame came from. Yours and the one on ebay appear to be the only two in the world.

Answer (score -1):

Bmx panther originally made in colarado i recall.

Comment: Do you have a picture? I find nothing called BMX Panther that looks like the posted frame.